# NVIDIA drivers frequent crashes while playing Mu Online even after multiple fresh reinstall

Tags: windows-10, drivers, crash, nvidia-graphics-card

I play a videogame called Mu Online. Since many time ago, I suffer from constant experience of two errors: either the window closes completely or it go full dark:

[image: Mu window crashing]

I've already asked friends who also experience these problems and they suggest this may be the result of playing too many windows (I play with 10 acc), but that wouln't be my case since my PC supports this and more (with 10 windows GPU goes 50% and CPU around the same). Some posts on web suggested that crashes in driver may the result of overheeting, but I already checked my GPU's temperature and it's all fine. Now recently I learned about Event Manager of W10 and I started to monitor these black-screens or closings and noticed that most of the time it's a NVIDIA driver related issue. It just keeps failing time after time! Eve if I do a reinstall, it doesn't take much time for the first black screen to appear.

Here are some prints of the crash reports:

[image: Case 1]

[image: Case 2]

[image: Case 3]

[image: Case 4]

[image: Case 5]

[image: Case 6]

[image: Case 7]

(Sorry for being in Portuguese)

So can I do for my NVIDIA graphics driver just start working properly?!

PC Specs:

- AMD Ryzen 7 1800x
- MSI NVIDIA GTX 1060 6Gb
- 16 GB RAM Corsair Vengeance 3200MHz
- SSD Samsung Evo 960 256Gb
- Windows 10
- PSU EVGA 750 W

Bonus info: after also suffering from BSOD related to the NVDIA driver, I did some Google research and some people suggested reinstalling some .dll from a extract.exe call in cmd. When I was considering doing so, I found out my drivers were in a completely different subdirectory:

Where it was supposed to be: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers`
Where it was: `C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_77e6900053c33f6f`

Comment: OpenGL is not good at sharing memory; it will also likely buffer any used memory back into system RAM too. 10 instances of a game is simply too high an expectation for 6GB GPU RAM & 16GB system RAM. Unless you can restrict each game to 384MB GPU RAM or less, you need to reduce your concurrent players.

Comment: @Tetsujin well I'll have to disagree. Mu Online is not a computer-demanding process, it's not like I'm playing 10 Crysis here. As I noticed above, even when playing with 10 windows I reach only 50% of my PC's potential for both GPU, CPU and RAM. And I have already opened 13, 14 windows with no aditional lag. I have already played 10 windows plus statistical operations with MT5 consuming 100% of my CPU with no window crash. So the hypothesis of PC limitation is very unlikely true.

Comment: Do any of the other processes you mention use OpenGL? My initial guess still stands. I work support line for an online game based on OGL & this is one of our common GPU crash/timeout issues. Though it's not a direct comparison, on a 12-core machine with reasonable GPU & 64GB RAM, I can run as many instances of the game as I like… so long as I make sure I restrict each to minimal texture memory, 128MB or even lower & don't ever run Photoshop at the same time [as that also uses OGL]. I can increase this limit by making a character face a wall, so almost nothing is being drawn.

Comment: @Tetsujin Oh and such crashes occur also with less open windows such as 7 or 5.

Comment: @Tetsujin Hmm well in that case, I'll try a patch I know exists that limits the details of the graphs of the game (which are already on its minimal by its own configuration options). Let's see the results. Apart from that, I must notice that not all crashes are OGL related considering what I can understand from the crash reports and that some times I can run as much as 1 or 2 weeks without any crash and in other periods they occur with half an hour of difference, some times multiple windows at once. If OGL was the issue, I can't see why this would happen this way.

Comment: You really need to know precisely which parameters are affected by sweeping controller changes such as 'high, medium, low' on a game. Sometimes dropping graphics settings to low will switch off CPU & GPU optimisations that you may do better switched on; & push GPU-optimised tasks back onto your CPU. These will not necessarily reflect in your overall CPU usage. Game optimisation is not a simple task, & not obvious which optimisations will be good or bad on any specific machine. Multiply that uncertainty by 10 & you have a tightrope walk.